# Kubernetes difference between activeDeadlineSeconds in Job and Pod

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes provides a `activeDeadlineSeconds` field for both `JobSpec` and `PodSpec`

What is the difference between the two? I've put together a little job with `activeDeadlineSeconds` set to 20, and in its Pod definition I have set the `activeDeadlineSeconds` field to 45. These are kind of arbitrary but meant to be spaced out. When I create/apply the Job then run `kubectl get pods -a --watch`, I can see that the 20 deadline isn't having any effect but the second one is (I see the `DeadlineExceeded` output).

Just to be extra certain, I added `terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10` in the PodSpec and see the same thing.

What is the purpose of the `activeDeadlineSeconds` in the Job? It doesn't seem to be sending any signal to my container.

Note: I'm simply running the `sleep` command on an `ubuntu` image. This command should exit when receiving the TERM signal sent by Kubernetes (so I expect a TERM signal at 20 seconds then the pod to die shortly thereafter)

Condensed YAML definition:

```
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1  # K8s 1.7.x
kind: CronJob
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  jobTemplate:
    spec:  # JobSpec
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 20   # This needs to be shorter than the cron interval  ## TODO - NOT WORKING!
      parallelism: 1
      template:  # PodTemplateSpec
        spec:
          activeDeadlineSeconds: 45
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
          containers:
          - name: ubuntu-container
            image: ubuntu
            command: ['bash', '-c', 'sleep 500000']
```

References:

- https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#jobspec-v1-batch
- https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#podspec-v1-core
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429594/why-sigterm-is-able-to-kill-sleep

Comment: Can you post the YAML of your Job definition?

Comment: I just modified the post. I've removed all fields that aren't relevant

Comment: FYI, my actual goal is to periodically ensure that I have X number of pods running. Pods can die off naturally if they like (and _remain dead_), but when the time comes, I'd like to kill off any and all remaining and bring up a new set. This can be done in many ways but I thought for sure that `CronJob` with `Job` that specifies `activeDeadlineSeconds` is the easiest.

Comment: looks like you are hitting https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/10755 / https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/32149 which is fixed... in 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community wiki answer for future:

As per @Clorichel this issue was fixed in k8s v1.8
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/32149

My advice is to upgrade your cluster to the latest version, if is possible to have access to newest features and bug fixes.

Answer (score 6):

Since this comes up when Googling more or less what the subject line of this post says, I thought I would add a clarifying answer.

I had to do a little bit of digging to understand the difference, but it's clear from the Kubernetes documentation after I re-read it a couple of times.

The `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` on a Pod will kill the pod while the `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` on a Job will kill **all** pods owned by that job.

Another difference, and the key for my test case, is that when using `ResourceQuotas`, you can specify a resource quota as below to allow a certain number of pods which are Not Terminating pods. In my case below, it is 0 so as to prevent any non-job pods in the namespace from being scheduled.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: no-non-terminating-pods
  namespace: default
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "0"
  scopeSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - operator: Exists
      scopeName: NotTerminating
```

Initially, this blocked my `Pod` which is owned by a `CronJob`, because the `jobTemplate.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` was set:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: some-job
  namespace: default
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 43800
```

What I needed was to set it in the `Pod.spec`, so I have added it in both places as below, however note that for `ResourceQuota` purposes only the `Pod.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` is needed.

I want the job to kill all of its pods (1 pod since I'm not using `parallelism`), rather than for the pod to kill itself, but I also want to block pods which are not going to be terminated by a deadline.

So to accomplish this, my `CronJob` now looks like this. The Job's `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` will kill all of its child pods at the deadline specified in the `jobTemplate.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`, and the `ResourceQuota` specified above will prevent any pods without their own `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` from being scheduled in the namespace in the first place.

So to allow the job pod to be scheduled, we must set it in both places, and set the Pod's `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` to a higher value than the Job's `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` in order to prevent the pod from being killed prematurely. This is of course a special use case, but I thought it would be helpful to demonstrate the difference.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: some-job
  namespace: default
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 43800
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: zap-scan
        spec:
          activeDeadlineSeconds: 44600
```